# marketing Cloud - super messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, mobilepush, sms, entitlements

(1) Does SFMC have a feature within it, so as to calculate the usage of super messages and different channel usage ?? and DOES SF track and charge as of today / now their customers for super messages usage, as to my understanding it is that as SF doe snot have this as a feature in SFMC so they dont track the usage.

(2)can anyone help me navigate to entitlements in SFMC, i went into setup but dont find any entitlement even through quick find/ search , so as to check the super messages.

Answer (score 1):

**Super message consumption** is not displayed anywhere in the interface in Marketing Cloud, nor is there any API that can provide that information. This is all hidden to the end user, but SF does track that and will charge you (sooner or later) if you go over the limits.

Account Executives or Success Managers (or however they are called now) could give you reports on how far along you are in consuming the resources allotted in your current contract.

Your only option to get the utilization information would be to stitch the reporting yourself from various reports and data views, so that you would have at least a rough estimate.

---

**Entitlement management** is not really a thing in Marketing Cloud.

The only thing that allows you to give you some control over the relationship of your users with SF Support agent is the Salesforce Help Portal.

If you have a Premier or Signature Success Plan, you can go into the [settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/settings) and assign [Designated Contacts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386786&type=1) and control their privileges:

[image]